# Applying a jinja filter after using groupby filter

Tags: python, group-by, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries that I want to group by a certain attribute and then sum by another. For a variable 'foo' this would be something like:

```
foo | groupby('a') | sum(attribute='b')
```

This clearly won't work because after the `groupby`, I have a list of tuples. Is there any way to unpack the tuple and then repack it, so that i can maintain the work done by `groupby`, but work on the second tuple value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`map()` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) to apply a sum to each group, provided you extract the group list first:

```
foo | groupby('a') | map(attribute='list') | map('sum', attribute='b')
```

That's because `map()` takes the first argument as another filter, and the remainder of the arguments are passed to that filter, applying that filter to each element of `groupby()`.

This does mean you end up with a list of sums, not with groups.

You cannot apply the summing to the groups and leave the `.grouper` attribute in place. For that the only solution is to use an actual loop:

```
{% for group in foo | groupby('a') %}
    {{ group.grouper }}: {{ group.list | sum(attribute='b') }}
{% endfor %}
```

would output each distinct value of `a` followed by a colon and the sum of attribute `b` for that group.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Though unfortunate that I loose the `grouper`. It would've been nice if I could've extracted the `a` attribute with the `sum` operation to maintain the grouping.