# Group by loop parametrs

Tags: php, symfony

How can I group output result by "item.hotel.name" ?

```
{% for item in pagination.items %}   <!-- Вывод результатов по отелям -->
            <div class="row">
              {{item.hotel.name->item2 }}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1">{{ loop.index }}</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <span class="text-capitalize">{{ item.hotel.name }}</span>
                        <span class="text-primary">{{ item.roomName }}</span>
                        {% if(item.mealName) %}
                            <span class="text-muted">({{ item.mealName }})</span>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">{{ item.price }} {{ item.currency }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Now:
   [image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: In your dql have you used the groupedBy() function ?

Comment: Have you seen this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598163/twig-loop-grouping?rq=1

Comment: And i don't undestand    {% for hotel.name in pagination|group_by(=>_.name) %}   <!-- Вывод результатов по отелям -->