# How to group by column name in Twig?

Tags: php, twig, slim-3

I am trying to group in `for` loop using Twig. I have found an extension for Twig which adds additional features to twig. Here is the link for that: [twig-lambda](https://github.com/dpolac/twig-lambda). When I am trying to group by `skillcategory` it shows two times instead once.

Here is the data i get:

```
[
  {
    "0": {
      "skillid": 1,
      "skillname": "PHP",
      "skillcategory": "Programing Langugages",
      "skilllevel": 62
    },
    "4": {
      "skillid": 5,
      "skillname": "C#",
      "skillcategory": "Programing Langugages",
      "skilllevel": 50
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "skillid": 2,
      "skillname": "Walking",
      "skillcategory": "Others",
      "skilllevel": 20
    },
    "2": {
      "skillid": 3,
      "skillname": "Jumping",
      "skillcategory": "Others",
      "skilllevel": 100
    },
    "3": {
      "skillid": 4,
      "skillname": "Naping",
      "skillcategory": "Others",
      "skilllevel": 80
    }
  }
]
```

What I actually want to get

```
Programing Langugages
PHP, C#

Others
Walking, Jumping, Naping
```

And it is my version of twig code:

```
{% for key, i in skills|group_by(=> _.skillcategory) %}
   {% for b in i %}
       <div>{{b.skillcategory}}</div>
       {{b.skillname}}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Just print category outside for statement.

```
{% for key, i in skills|group_by(=> _.skillcategory) %}
   {{ key }}

   {% for b in i %}
       {{ b.skillname }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just tested and it worked out for me!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your JSON in not valid!

Try with this :

```
[
  {
    "0": {
      "skillid": 1,
      "skillname": "PHP",
      "skillcategory": "Programin Langugages",
      "skilllevel": 62
    },
    "4": {
      "skillid": 5,
      "skillname": "C#",
      "skillcategory": "Programin Langugages",
      "skilllevel": 50
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "skillid": 2,
      "skillname": "Walking",
      "skillcategory": "Others",
      "skilllevel": 20
    },
    "2": {
      "skillid": 3,
      "skillname": "Jumping",
      "skillcategory": "Others",
      "skilllevel": 100
    },
    "3": {
      "skillid": 4,
      "skillname": "Naping",
      "skillcategory": "Others",
      "skilllevel": 80
    }
  }
]
```

Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.

Edit:
I m not sure but try with this:

```
{% for key, i in ['Programin Langugages', 'Others']|group_by(=> _.skillcategory) %}
   {% for b in i %}
       <div>{{b.skillcategory}}</div>
       {{b.skillname}}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But it also returns not grouped data.

Comment: that doesn't work for me. Json is a data sourced from `skills`.

Comment: @ElvinHuseynov then i have nothing else to help :( Check this post looks similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598163/twig-loop-grouping